# Why im not able to get the return value from a debounced function with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hi want to implement a debounce function for each api call happening my the api GET code are written in `action.js` of vuex

**Here is my debounce function

implementation in Utils**.

```
export function debounce(fn, wait = 1000, id){
    let timer = {};
   return function(...args){
     let uniqueId = args[1].params[id];
     if(timer[uniqueId]) {
        clearTimeout(timer[uniqueId]); // clear any pre-existing timer
     }
     const context = this; // get the current context
     timer[uniqueId] = setTimeout(()=>{
        return fn.apply(context, args); // call the function if time expires
     }, wait);
   }
}
```

**action.js**

```
import {debounce} from '../../Utils'   
export default {
    getPosts : debounce(async function(context, payload = {}) {
       let resp = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, payload);
       if (resp.status == 200) {
         return resp.data;
       }else {
         throw ` Error statusText-->${resp.statusText}`;
       }
   },500,id)
}
```

Now the above `vuex`  action is wrapped with `debounce` function

here is how i'm calling `getPosts()` function

```
...
methods:{
    getPosts({id:this.getUUID()}).then((data) => {
        console.log('posts..........',data);   //data ->  undefined
    });

},
```

Comment: Well you're wrapping an `async`  funciton in your debounce, but your debounce method doesn't return an async function or a promise. Have you tried to make the debounce return an async function? Like `return async function ...`?

Comment: @vstm i have not tried that, because exactly i don't know how to code for that.